# Can't install Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli, npm-install

No matter how many times i tried... i can't install Angular CLI on my computer...

I'm using:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

And this is the console error log:

```
C:\Users\Félix Bejarano\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\Félix Bejarano\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Félix Bejarano\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\Félix Bejarano\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\Félix Bejarano\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat \'C:\\Users\\Félix Bejarano\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'lstat',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\Félix Bejarano\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Félix Bejarano\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-27T22_56_59_735Z-debug.log
```

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried *running this command again as root/Administrator*, like the error message says?

Comment: Yes i did, at least five times

Comment: as in opening a command prompt as Administrator and trying the install from there?

You can also try to nuke `C:\\Users\\Félix Bejarano\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular` and then running again

Comment: Nuke? What is that?

Comment: you could try adding `sudo` infront of the command or `--force`at the end of the command so `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` or `npm install -g @angular/cli --force`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in a windows command line:

First create a directory called `npm-global` or something directly under `C:\` with the same user OR create this under your user name. `C:\users\myuserId`. Side note:- the `é` character in your username `C:\Users\Félix Bejarano` could a problem - I don't know.

Run following command in a Command window - (for bash etc you adjust the paths)

`npm config --global set prefix c:\npm-global\npm`

then

`npm config --global set cache C:\npm-global\npm-cache`

This will get you a clean folder that you have access to.

Comment: it worked after 3 years, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have homebrew installed then you can use,

```
brew install angular-cli
```